# creating an n-branch tree in C language, can't find any example

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I have read about linked lists and also binary trees. What I am not able to find anywhere is an n-branch tree. Let me be more elaborate. When we goto the system manager in our Windows OS, we find a list of devices. Usually a device can be clicked on to have another "child" list under that device. These children may have their own "child" lists as well (potentially). Where I can find such a parent-child n-tree program example/tutorial?

What I mean by n-tree is that, it does not have just 2 brances. It can have any number of branches at any level of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fixed number of branches you can do something like

```
typedef struct _node_t
{
  void *data;
  struct _node_t *branch[50];
} node_t;
```

OR

```
typedef struct _node_t
{
  void *data;
  struct _node_t **branch;
} node_t;
```

Then for each allocated node, allocate the number of branches in the array.

```
node_t *node;
node = malloc (sizeof (node_t));
node->branch = malloc (sizeof (node_t *) * number_of_branches_for_this_node);
//Then
node->branch[i]; //To access the branch.
```

To determine the end of number of branches, you may want to store the number of branches in that particular node, or store NULL or other magic number in the last location of the `branch` array.

Also a note, when freeing a node you must free the `branch` array first before freeing the node.

```
free (node->branch);
free (node);
```

Comment: well in this case, I am looking for many branches. It shall be decided at run time so the 2nd option looks correct. Is there some document where I can read about this stuff in detail? Also are these things called just "trees"?

Comment: Yes, this is a tree. If you don't have a loop in the structure, it is a tree or if there are `n` nodes and number of links are `n-1` then it is a tree. The direction of the links are implicit.

Comment: hmm, I was expecting that. The issue has been that whenever I search for tree in C language I just get binary trees that I have had enough of. So I just got fed up and posted the question here instead.

Comment: See more definitions from Graph Theory: [Tree in Graph theory context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) and [Tree in Datastructure context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29)

Comment: Yes I have read this, I was talking more about the source code for these list boxes that are able to show such trees.

Comment: Yes it is a general tree, but i think general is implicit when we talk on the context of graphs.